# Call PHP program as popup overlay?

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to use fancybox iframe to call a PHP program for payment processing from a javascript program as part of a landing page. The page also calls another PHP program that writes date to a file. I tried to simulate a click to start the fancybox function but never got it to work. I keep getting this error - $("a.hiddenclicker").fancybox is not a function. I'm not sure whether to attempt to just add this logic to the PHP file or figure out how to get fancybox to work. Here is my page. The call to fancybox is in ProcessForm().

```
function WriteData(url) {
var j1 = document.getElementById("hiddenclicker"); 

  var Request2 = false;  
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    Request2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    Request2 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  if (Request2) {   
    Request2.open("GET", url, true); 
    Request2.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (Request2.readyState == 4 && Request2.status == 200) {
              }
    }
    Request2.send(null);


  }
}


  function ProcessForm(form) {
    var j1 = document.getElementById("hiddenclicker"); 
    var firstname = "";
    var lastname = "";
    var payment = "";
    var email = "";
    var phone = "";
    var donation = "";
    firstname = form.firstname.value;
    lastname = form.lastname.value;
    email = form.email.value;
    phone = form.phone.value;
    donation = form.donation.value;
    if (firstname == "") {
        alert("You must fill in the first name");
        form.firstname.focus();
        return false;
                }
    else {
        if (lastname == "") {
            alert("You must fill in last name");
            form.lastname.focus();
            return false;
        }
    else {
        if (email == "") {
            alert("You must fill in email address");
            form.email.focus();
            return false; }
        }
    } 
    WriteData("writedata.php?firstname=" + firstname + "&lastname=" + lastname + "&email=" + email + "&phone=" + phone + "&donation=" + donation);


if (donation == "now") {

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.hiddenclicker").fancybox(
    {
        'width' : 600,
        'height' : 400,
        'hideOnContentClick' : false,
        'type' : 'iframe'
    });
     });    
  j1.href = "http://www.ccyakids.org/donation_logic/donation_start.php#form";   
  $('#hiddenclicker').trigger('click'); 
}
```

}

// End hiding JavaScript statements -->

HTML needed to trigger hiddenclicker

Hidden Clicker

Comment: Think I needed this as well for hiddenclicker <div id="hidden_clicker" style="display:none;">
  <a id="hiddenclicker" href="http://www.ccyakids.org/donation_logic/donation_start.php#form" >Hidden Clicker</a>
    </div>

Comment: is Jquery and fancybox included on the page <script src="..." type="..."></script>? Do you have a link for further debugging? is there in fact a link with the class hiddenclicker as you suggest? $("a.hiddenclicker")

Comment: Here is the [link]http://www.1000give100.org/landing-page.html @TimWickstrom.com

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code you reference your link 2 different ways:

```
$("a.hiddenclicker") // class
$('#hiddenclicker') // ID
```

Which is it? Make them both the same and i am sure your problem goes away.

Hope this helps

Comment: I made them both $("a.hiddenclicker") and still get the error $("a.hiddenclicker").fancybox is not a function. The link again is [link]http://www.1000give100.org/landing-page.html @TimWickstrom.com

Comment: I figured out this problem I wasn't including all of the .js files that were needed. Now the overlay quickly comes up but doesn't get focus and I don't see the PHP program in the overlay. Here is the actual code that that.

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $("a.php-overlay").fancybox(
  {
    'width' : 600,
    'height' : 400,
    'hideOnContentClick' : false,
    'type' : 'iframe'
   });
   }); 
   j1.href = "http://www.ccyakids.org/donation_logic/donation_start.php#form"; 
   $('#hiddenclicker').trigger('click');

Comment: 'code' jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $("a.php-overlay").fancybox(
  {
    'width' : 600,
    'height' : 400,
    'hideOnContentClick' : false,
    'type' : 'iframe'
   });
   }); 
   j1.href = "http://www.ccyakids.org/donation_logic/donation_start.php#form"; 
   $('#hiddenclicker').trigger('click');